# python dict key order based on values - recursive solution

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, recursion, dependencies

(In python 3.6)
How do I output a list of the dictionary keys in which the order of the list is based on the dictionary value dependencies? For example, if I have a dictionary of software programs with values that indicate other programs upon which it is dependent:

```
packages = { 'B7': ['R3'], 
             'R3': ['timestmp', 'Abbot', '9K'],
             'tempor': ['cavie', 'sandals', 'B7'],
             'Abbot': ['Duns'],
             'timestmp': [],
             'Duns': [] }
```

I would return a list with each item ordered based on the programs necessary to install. So I would install 'timestmp' before 'R3'.

```
>>> get_download_order(packages)
['timestmp', 'Duns', 'Abbot', '9K', 'R3', 'B7', 'cavie', 'sandals', 'tempor']

# The list doesn't have to result in this exact order 
# as long as the download order of packages will work.
```

For a non-recursive solution, I was thinking of doing a tree with children, and identify the parent, then you could traverse the tree. But apparently, there is a recursive solution, and I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is known as [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), from the Wikipedia:

> In the field of computer science, a topological sort or topological
>   ordering of a directed graph is a linear ordering of its vertices such
>   that for every directed edge uv from vertex u to vertex v, u comes
>   before v in the ordering.

In your particular case the vertex of the graph are the packages and the edges are the dependencies. You can solve the problem using [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm) (no recursion), an implementation below:

```
def toposort(graph):
    # init the indegree for each noe
    nodes = graph.keys() | set([node for adjacents in graph.values() for node in adjacents])
    in_degree = {node: 0 for node in nodes}

    # compute the indegree
    for k, adjacents in graph.items():
        for node in adjacents:
            in_degree[node] += 1

    # init the heap with the nodes with indegree 0 and priority given by key
    heap = [node for node, degree in in_degree.items() if degree == 0]

    top_order = []
    while heap:  # heap is not empty
        node = heap.pop()  # get the element with highest priority and remove from heap
        top_order.append(node)  # add to topological order
        for adjacent in graph.get(node, []):  # iter over the neighbors of the node
            in_degree[adjacent] -= 1
            if in_degree[adjacent] == 0:  # if the node has in_degree 0 add to the heap with priority given by key
                heap.append(adjacent)

    return top_order


packages = {'B7': ['R3'],
            'R3': ['timestmp', 'Abbot', '9K'],
            'tempor': ['cavie', 'sandals', 'B7'],
            'Abbot': ['Duns'],
            'timestmp': [],
            'Duns': []}

reverse = {}
for key, nodes in packages.items():
    for node in nodes:
        reverse.setdefault(node, []).append(key)


print(toposort(reverse))
```

**Output**

```
['timestmp', '9K', 'sandals', 'Duns', 'Abbot', 'R3', 'B7', 'cavie', 'tempor']
```

**Note**

For the proposed solution to work it needs the reversed graph, that is what the following lines do:

```
reverse = {}
for key, nodes in packages.items():
    for node in nodes:
        reverse.setdefault(node, []).append(key)
```

Also note that the order is not unique, for instance in your example both `'timestmp'` and `'Duns'` could be the first package to install, given that they don't have any dependencies.

**Further**

- A discussion of Kanh's algorithm along with implementations: [topological sorting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting-indegree-based-solution/).
- A recursive solution can be done using (a recursive) Depth-First Search (DFS) to solve  the topological sort, you can find a good discussion of a recursive DFS [here](https://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/).
- For using DFS for solving Topological sorting see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Depth-first_search).

Comment: This solution fails if there are no dependencies, as you can verify by setting `packages = {"B7": [], "R3": []}` (it returns an empty list).

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192626/deceptively-simple-implementation-of-topological-sorting-in-python):

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Set

def topological_sort(graph: Dict[str, List[str]]) -> List[str]:
    result: List[str] = []
    seen: Set[str] = set()

    def recursive_helper(node: str) -> None:
        for neighbor in graph.get(node, []):
            if neighbor not in seen:
                seen.add(neighbor)
                recursive_helper(neighbor)
        if node not in result:
            result.append(node)

    for key in graph.keys():
        recursive_helper(key)
    return result


packages = {'B7': ['R3'],
            'R3': ['timestmp', 'Abbot', '9K'],
            'tempor': ['cavie', 'sandals', 'B7'],
            'Abbot': ['Duns'],
            'timestmp': [],
            'Duns': []}

print(topological_sort(packages))
```

### Output

```py
['timestmp', 'Duns', 'Abbot', '9K', 'R3', 'B7', 'cavie', 'sandals', 'tempor']
```

This also works without dependencies:

```py
packages = {"B7": [], "R3": []}
print(topological_sort(packages))
```

### Output

```py
['B7', 'R3]
```