# How to find line-sequence from pandas.dataframe, python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have several lines defined in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'from': ['p2', 'p3', 'p1'],
        'to': ['p3', 'p4', 'p2'],
    },
    index=['line_b', 'line_c', 'line_a'],
)

# How to get line_sequence as ['line_a', 'line_b', 'line_c']?
```

Each line has a `from` point and a `to` point. These lines are connected in certain sequence. In this example, the sequence is `line_a --> line_b --> line_c`.

Could you please show me how to quickly find the connection sequence based on the columns of `from` and `to`? In the example above, there are numbers in the points' names, like `'p1'` and `'p2'`. It is just an example. In my real application, the names could be any string.

The expected outcome should be in the format of `List[str]`.

Thanks.

Comment: You need topological sorting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192626/deceptively-simple-implementation-of-topological-sorting-in-python

Comment: This looks like a network problem. Try [networkx](https://networkx.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['p2', 'p3', 'p1'], 'to': ['p3', 'p4', 'p2'], }, index=['line_b', 'line_c', 'line_a'])

# create graph
df = df.reset_index()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "from", "to", edge_attr="index", create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# store edge attributes
index = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "index")


# find topological sort
order = nx.topological_sort(nx.line_graph(G))

# map to index
res = [index[edge] for edge in order]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['line_a', 'line_b', 'line_c']
```